# Get first key in a JSON array in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

If my response from my API looks like this.

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get the first key in the errors in dart?
Currently I am doing

```
var body = json.decode(response.body);
print(body['errors']['email']);
```

But ['email'] could be dynamic, I just want whatever the first entry is of the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try something like:

```
print(body['errors'].keys.toList()[0]);
```

Comment: Beware... ".keys" could come out in any order.  "First" doesn't really make sense here.  Luckily your example has only one. :)